# EF - An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager when adding existing entity to Association

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

so I've posted a question earlier but didn't receive much feedback. Could be that I've explained it wrong. When you're knowledge is limited it's hard to ask the right question.

To summarize, I have three EF entities: Books, Pages and Content - The book has many pages and a page has only one content.

**I already have content entries**, I don't need to create them, just reference them in my Page entity. So what I'm trying to do is this:

```
//Add a new Book
var myBook = new Book();
//Add a new page
var myPage = new Page();

//I'm selecting this one from an asp.net dropdown box
var myContent = contentService.get(id); 

//Connect the page and content
myPage.Content = myContent;

//Add a page to the book
myBook.Pages.Add(myPage)
```

When I add the first page, everything is fine but when I try to add a second one to my book i get an exception. If I comment out the line where I assign myContent to the navigation property (myPage.Content = myContent) the error is gone.

The big question is... How do I add a new book with 2 or more pages (2 new entries in the database) when pages are referring to an already existing database entry?

Comment: Are you trying to add the second page in the same process? or your page i already exist in the data base and you try to add the second page?

Comment: nothing is saved in a database at this point. database only contains content entries. what i'm trying to do is create a new book, then a new page (with an already existing content in database), and another one, and another one... once I'm done with that, I wanna save a new book (a database entry) and all of its pages (a number of database entries that contain a FK to content)

Comment: In your relationships for 'Page' is it ok for 2 pages to reference the same content? That's what the problem looks like here (unless 'Id' is being changed to something else on each call).

Comment: it's perfectly fine if two Pages have the same content. Would that be a problem to EF?

Comment: Are the DB generation Options correct on your ID field on the enity that fails.  Check that key. if it isnt marked as Exteranlly genrated in EF, to ids with the value 0 will do this.

Comment: @esper it would be if your Page table has its Id/ContentId as a composite key. How is your Page table setup?

Comment: I have no solution but a critical remark about your question and why you don't get an answer: The question is thrown by Entity Framework. In your code snippet isn't a single line of code that has anything to do with Entity Framework, you are just creating objects, adding objects to collection properties and call a method nobody knows what it does exactly. There is no `ObjectContext` or `DbContext`, no context set, no EF method like `AddObject`/`Add` or `Attach` or `SaveChanges`, etc. It's impossibe to answer your question based on the information you provided.

Comment: I believe the problem lies on the one to one relationship of `Page` and `Content`. It should be a many(Page) to one(Content) relationship.

Comment: I removed my answer, but this link will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086721/an-object-with-the-same-key-already-exists-in-the-objectstatemanager?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Swap two lines:

```
myBook.Pages.Add(myPage);
myPage.Content = myContent;
```

Reason is that `myBook.Pages.Add(myPage)` changes the state of the whole object graph in `myPage` to `Added`. So if you add the page first and then assign the content, the content remains `Unchanged`.

Comment: I've tried so many things, this one being one of them but now I cant remember if I got the same error. I'll try this and get back to you. About the comment on re-posting - you're right, I'm gonna remove my first question